# Convert tradingview's pine script to python

Tags: python, pine-script, binance-api-client

I want to convert the following Pine script to python to calculate the value for vwap1 variable without plotting the results, I just want to calculate the value for vwap1:

```
wapScore(pds) =>
    mean = sum(volume*close,pds)/sum(volume,pds)
    vwapsd = sqrt(sma(pow(close-mean, 2), pds) )
    (close-mean)/vwapsd

vwap1 = input(48)
plot(vwapScore(vwap1),title="ZVWAP2-48",color=#35e8ff, linewidth=2,transp=0.75)
```

I have tried the following:

```
def calculate_SMA(ser, days):
    sma = ser.rolling(window=days).mean()
    return sma


def calculate_Zscore(pds, volume, close):
    mean = sum(volume * close, pds) / sum(volume, pds)
    vwapsd = np.sqrt(calculate_SMA(pow(close - mean, 2), pds))
    return (close - mean) / vwapsd
```

And I am using `calculate_Zscore` function to calculate the value and add it to pandas dataframe
but it gives me different values rather than the values on trading view

```
candles["Zscroe-48"] = zscore.calculate_Zscore(48,candles["Volume"], candles["Close"])
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or what I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is in `mean`.
Try this:

```
def calculate_SMA(ser, pds):

    sma = ser.rolling(window=pds).mean()
    return sma

def calculate_Zscore(pds,df):

    df['mean'] = ((df['Close']*df['Volume']).rolling(pds).sum())/df['Volume'].rolling(pds).sum()
    #mean = sum(volume * close, pds) / sum(volume, pds)
    df['vwapsd'] = np.sqrt(calculate_SMA(pow(df['Close'] - df['mean'], 2), pds))
    #df['z-scoor'] = (df['Close'] - df['mean']) / df['vwapsd']
    return (df['Close'] - df['mean']) / df['vwapsd']
```

Comment: I have tried it but calculate_SMA(ser, pds) function is returning series with NaN values - do you have an idea why is that?